# Firebase Authentication - blocking functions - not working - trigger not visible

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have two problems

1. I tried to set specific created function earlier and was unable to make it work. I've chosen function, all saved but when trigger happens I get:

```
BLOCKING_FUNCTION_ERROR_RESPONSE : HTTP Cloud Function returned an error: 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/func-auth</code> from this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Even thou I have All Traffic allowed.

Okay, so decided to create special function for it.
Created gen1  function via UI, picked Firebase Auth -> create:

```
 Firebase Authentication PREVIEW
Event typecreate
```

and this function is not even visible in Firebase project to choose from

All over internet I found only issues about emulators, I don't use such. I'm tryibng to run this on running GCP env.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. Firebase is .. not autheticating as any? Or I don't know how to find one. I've just allowed role   = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" for member = "allUsers" and it works. But this is FAAAAR from what it should be in case of security. I can't find the SA for Firebase thou

Comment: Please include the source code (redacted as necessary) of your Cloud Function.

Comment: @samthecodingman but the function is not triggered at all. I only have logging param currently: 
export const beforecreated = beforeUserCreated((event) => { console.log(event) });

Comment: The reason I asked is it allows us to see if there is anything wrong with the way that you export the function. Importantly, I am trying to figure out where `/func-auth` is coming from.

Comment: @samthecodingman but this is about function visibility in Firebase or Forbidden error? 
I've just created function via terraform:
  event_trigger {
    event_type = "providers/firebase.auth/eventTypes/user.create"
    resource   = "projects/${data.google_project.project.name}"
    failure_policy {
      retry = false
    }
  }
and it still is not visible in Firebase project. Only http triggered ones. This is so weird that dedicated trigger is not working. Looks very 'preview'

Comment: Your code defines a `beforeCreate` function, but that has an event type of [`providers/cloud.auth/eventTypes/user.beforeCreate`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/5a94583e42a4263f131dcd78a84af6899a054e94/src/v1/providers/auth.ts#L156-L215). Based on your comment, you've used the event type of `onCreate`.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for keep helping me :) 
Yeah, it's true but I think that's not event definition for GCP cloud functions. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/firebase-auth and I've just tried changing and I get bad request saying for unknown event trigger. So it has to be the user.create - which is very weird cause Firebase does not have 'delete' but has on login.

Comment: Okay, I think that trigger is different. Just found out that function must be http function :) Will experiment with that. I was able to run the preview trigger - it run itself but it's not blocking Firebase flow. And because of that I need to make that http function working with the firebase flow. Something to try out in the evening :) Once I'm finished I will post the answer - if able :D Thanks!